# How to make a child elements (<div> and <div) clickable with a sibling <a> wrapped inside an <li> without jQuery

Tags: html, css

So I have this structure now:

```
<li>
 <div><hx></div>
 <a><img></a>
 <div><p></p></div>
</li>
```

I have all the css set up and everything looks good, but at the last minute I find out that not just the img, but a h and p also need to be clickable. Is there a easy way to make the whole li clickable, without disturbing the existing css? May be like a ghost element I can wrap the whole thing in?

Comment: Did you try onMouseClick event on `li` using JavaScript?

Comment: HTML5 allows you to wrap `a` elements around block elements – so just make the `a` the outer element. (If your CSS relies on the specific order/relationship of the elements, small adjustments might be necessary.)

Comment: any header element. E.g :<h1> <h2> etc

Answer (score 1):

See the Snippet below for details on a ways to make `<li>` and contents clickable.

**Snippet**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Clickable</title>
<style>
li { list-style:none; }
a { text-decoration: none; }

</style>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Example 1</h3>
<h4>Wrap &lt;a&gt; around all of &lt;li&gt;'s content. <del>remove the extra &lt;div&gt;s</del>. Also add a `href="#"` to &lt;a&gt; even if you don't intend to have it jump to anywhere.</h4> 



  <li> 
  <a href="#">
      <h1>Without extra divs</h1>
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" width="128"> 
 <p>Content of a paragraph</p>
 </a>
</li>

  <li> 
  <a href="#">
      <div><h1>With extra divs</h1></div>
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png" width="128"> 
 <div><p>Content of a paragraph</p></div>
 </a>
</li>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot use this, because I already have a lot of CSS rules that will distort my existing markup. Also I looked up pointer-events but I'm not sure I can use that.

Comment: I removed the `point-events` example because I don't think it'll help in your circumstance. I have updated the answer. The CSS is just presentational and not required.

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo-element on the anchor positioned over the whole `li` would work.

I've made  the example as semi-transparent red but simple `opacity:0` or `background:rgba(0,0,0,0);` would work as well.

Now the whole `li` is clickable and links to wherever the anchor links to. No additional HTML or changed HTML and just a few extra lines of CSS.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  /* for demo */
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  /* for demo - should be transparent */
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <h1>My Heading</h1>
    </div>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/140.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortuantely, my anchor tag has a relative position, so the pseudo is occupying only the anchor.

Comment: Then that information really needed to be in the question. As it stands you will need to restructure the HTML or use Javascript.